# Objects duplicating every component mount. How can I make it run only once ? In react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

My object is a independent js file that I created.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    const widgetBuild = new window.WidgetFormBuilder({
        form: $(node).parents('#dynamic_form_wrapper')
    });
    widgetBuild.initForm();
}
```

Comment: Everytime it mounts it creates a new WidgetFormBuilder item using the same component the WidgetFormBuilder will get duplicated.

Comment: Make sure the component which has this componentDidMount lifecycle method doesn't get unmounted and recreated too often.

Comment: Maybe you can add componentWillUnmount lifecycle where you clear the widgetFormBuilder?? So every time it render, it shows only one widgetFormBuilder

Comment: Yeah i tried but I don't know what to put in the componentWillUnmount to clear the WidgetFormBuilder.

Comment: widgetBuild = null; should work.

Comment: But i initialized it inside the componentDidMount how am i gonna use it in componentWillUnmount ?

Comment: Save it in a class property and reference that from the unmount method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed i just added a .destroy() function in my WidgetFormBuilder. :)

```
WidgetFormBuilder.prototype.destroyBuilder = function () {
const self = this;

const destroyEvents = function () {
    $(self.form).unbind();
};

destroyEvents();

return this;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to workout without knowing more about `WidgetFormBuilder`.

However as good practice I would suggest...

```
componentDidMount() {
  const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
  // Assign to the class instance
  this.widgetBuild = new window.WidgetFormBuilder({
    form: $(node).parents('#dynamic_form_wrapper')
  });
  this.widgetBuild.initForm();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  // Cleanup
  // Check if WidgetFormBuilder has a destroy method or something similar.
  // See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount
  this.widgetBuild = null;
}

shouldComponentUpdate() {
  // Stop further re-renders, given you're using the DOM directly this could help prevent a few performance issues
  // See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate
  return false;
}
```

Finally, take a look at [the react docs on third party libs](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html).

Comment: WidgetFormBuilder is a JS plugin that I made for my Form Builder App.
I added WidgetFormBuilder in my global.d.ts file so that I can access it while i imported it in my twig file.